# Aligning text next to icon using :before

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to align my text next to my icon, however whatever I do, it doesn't work for some reason.

I try fiddling with `top` or `margin` however it still doesn't seem to want to align next to the icon. Any ideas?

CSS:

```
  .lock {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 36px;
    width: 30px;
    text-align: center;
}

.lock:before {
    content:url('https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/simplius-pack/512/pencil_and_paper-16.png');
    margin: 2px;
}

.subMenu-link {
    list-style:none;
    margin: -10px 0 10px;
    padding-left: 30px;
}

span {
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: pink;
}
```

HTML:

```
<li class="subMenu">
    <a href="">
        <i class="lock"></i>                   
        <span>User Account</span>
    </a>
    <ul class="subMenu-link">
        <li>One Link</li>
        <li>One Link</li>
        <li>One Link</li>
        <li>One Link</li>
    </ul>                               
</li>
```

the result shows this:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why are you using :before when you have the empty i tag that you want to add content before. Why just not add the icon as a background on the i tag (.lock) like this

```css
  .lock {
    background: url('https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/simplius-pack/512/pencil_and_paper-16.png') no-repeat center;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
  }
  .subMenu-link {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 10px 0;
    padding-left: 30px;
  }
  span {
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: pink;
    vertical-align: middle;
  }
```

```html
<li class="subMenu">
  <a href="">
    <i class="lock"></i> 
    <span>User Account</span>
  </a>
  <ul class="subMenu-link">
    <li>One Link</li>
    <li>One Link</li>
    <li>One Link</li>
    <li>One Link</li>
  </ul>
</li>

<li class="subMenu">
  <a href="">
    <i class="lock"></i> 
    <span>User Account</span>
  </a>
  <ul class="subMenu-link">
    <li>One Link</li>
    <li>One Link</li>
    <li>One Link</li>
    <li>One Link</li>
  </ul>
</li>

<li class="subMenu">
  <a href="">
    <i class="lock"></i> 
    <span>User Account</span>
  </a>
  <ul class="subMenu-link">
    <li>One Link</li>
    <li>One Link</li>
    <li>One Link</li>
    <li>One Link</li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you tried "vertical-align"  - it seems to work.

```
.lock:before {
    content:url('https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/simplius-pack/512/pencil_and_paper-16.png');
    vertical-align: -10%;    
}
```

[CODEPEN](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/lfzHk)

Answer (score 0):

if you want to centerize it vertically you can use the line-height
for example if the .lock height is 30px so set the line-height: to the span to 30px;